# Masonry.unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, layout

```
  UIView *v2 = ({
        UIView *view = [UIView new];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
        [view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(50, 50));
            make.left.equalTo(v1.mas_right);
            make.top.equalTo(v1.mas_bottom);
        }];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, -20, -20, -20);
        view;
    });


     UIView *v3 = ({
        UIView *view = [UIView new];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
        [view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(50, 50));
            make.centerY.equalTo(v2);
            make.left.equalTo(v2.mas_rightMargin);
//            make.left.equalTo(v2.mas_right);
        }];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        view;
    });
```

As you see, I am using the `Masonry` to create the UI.

This code has the bug.

> -[UIView mas_rightMargin]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdfa640cf80'

If I change the `make.left.equalTo(v2.mas_rightMargin);` to `make.left.equalTo(v2.mas_right);;`, it doesn't crash.

Comment: your crash is in `mas_leftMargin` or in `mas_rightMargin` ?? Your question is confusing

Comment: @ReinierMelian I edited my question.

Comment: for me your code works, just fine the only issue is that your current setup don't show any view because the disposition of your views

Answer (score 1):

Just set the Pods -> Masonry -> iOS Deployment Target to the target what your project is.
Here is the screenshot, wish to be helpful to you...

[image]